# Create one column to contain values from other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have time - series df like that:

| latitude | longitude | 2005 | 2006 | 2007 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 37.8766 | 30.5677 | 50.356 | 70.435 | 60.367 |
| 35.4578 | 30.7843 | 35.789 | 30.876 | 20.432 |

For time series analysis and forecasting I want to  create one year column for years above with  thier values ,the df could be like that:

| latitude | longitude | year | year'value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cell 1 | cell 2 | 2005 | 50.365 |
| cell 3 | cell 4 | 2006 | 70.435 |

Can I do that ? and how ?

I tried to reshape the df but it failed

Comment: Take a look at `pandas.melt` function. Especify your `id_vars` as `latitude, longitude` and your `value_vars` as `[2005, 2006, 2007]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reshape your dataframe using [`pd.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html):

```py
reshaped_df = df.melt(id_vars=['latitude', 'longitude'], var_name='year', value_name="year'value")
```

Which will give you:

```py
+----------+-----------+------+------------+
| latitude | longitude | year | year'value |
+----------+-----------+------+------------+
|  37.8766 |   30.5677 | 2005 |     50.356 |
|  35.4578 |   30.7843 | 2005 |     35.789 |
|  37.8766 |   30.5677 | 2006 |     70.435 |
|  35.4578 |   30.7843 | 2006 |     30.876 |
|  37.8766 |   30.5677 | 2007 |     60.367 |
|  35.4578 |   30.7843 | 2007 |     20.432 |
+----------+-----------+------+------------+
```